# Web developer moving to Winforms

Tags: c#, asp.net, winforms, flash

I have been doing ASP.NET / C# development for several years now.  I have recently been offered a project that will need to be a winforms application (I am assuming .net 2.0).

Specs:

- Winforms applicaton
- Application will
  have "testing for understanding
  questions"
- Must support flash and    camtasia
  files (these are "lessons")

I have done winforms development before, although nothing that is this involved. As there is a potential need for this application to be generic enough to apply to multiple different "disciplines", I would like to make the application generic enough to be easily configurable.  The caveat here is that the application will need to be run from a CD-ROM and that I cannot rely explicitly on an internet connection.  I was thinking of using something like SQL-Lite to support the configuration of the application.  There will not be the need for updating the application as it will not be updated (at least I don't think, I guess there is the possibility of the application calling a webservice and configuring its-self based upon returned values).

With the requirements of supporting Flash and Camtasia, along with making this application generic enough to support different "disciplines", and my self being an ASP.NET developer, does anyone have an recommendations or tips/ tricks to look out for?  Has anyone done something like this before?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd start by writing a user control that can be used to either display a video file (presumably the output from Camtasia) or a Shockwave app. Once you have that user control, I'd then move on to look at the overall app.

If you're using Winforms, and the software is supposed to run from the CD (instead of merely be installed from CD) you'll need to have the DotNet framework already on the computer I think - but then I'm not an expert in deployment.

I find the application model in Winforms to be a lot easier than WebForms, but then I was "raised" in thick clients, so I suppose I would.

I would also, whilst agreeing to WinForms if needs really must, encourage the client to give consideration to using WPF instead - which opens up the idea that you could also provide access over the web using a simlar interface using Silverlight...

Just a few thoughts anyway - good luck with it...

Comment: Good points . . . I am not sure about the file out put is on Camtasia.  As for the Usercontrol (is this analagous to usercontrols in asp.net?), are there any .net libraries out there for flash display with in a winforms app?  The web developer in me is still stuck in the "download the plugin" mentality.

Comment: Yes, a user control is in WinForms is the same idea... As for using flash with Winforms, have a read of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1037/displaying-flash-content-in-a-c-winforms-application