# C# and Flash integration

Tags: c#, flash

I have integrated C# and Flash with "Sockwave Flash Object".

I am trying to call a Flash method using a C# on-click event.

How to do this?

Comment: Forget Flash and use Silverlight :-)

Comment: I don't know how to use silverligt but im learning. Thank you for your proposal.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, there is a SO question that can help with how to use Shockwave Flash Object: [Displaying Flash content in a C# WinForms application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1037/displaying-flash-content-in-a-c-winforms-application)

Second, here is the Adobe Documentation: http://help.adobe.com/en_US/ActionScript/3.0_ProgrammingAS3/WS5b3ccc516d4fbf351e63e3d118a9b90204-7cb0.html

Most importantly (as to the answer) here is the directions on calling Flash methods in C#: http://blog.another-d-mention.ro/programming/communicate-betwen-c-and-an-embeded-flash-application/

Answer (score 1):

Flash can communicate with it's SWF container via the use of fscommand and ExternalInterface.