# C# application as container for Flex swf

Tags: c#, wpf, actionscript-3, flash

I do not want to [intertop between c# and AS3](http://blog.another-d-mention.ro/programming/communicate-betwen-c-and-an-embeded-flash-application/) or [here](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/ActionScript/3.0_ProgrammingAS3/WS5b3ccc516d4fbf351e63e3d118a9b90204-7cb0.html). I want a full screen content player in C# which can host a Adobe Flash swf file. Is there an example? In full screen, right clicks would have custom behavior attached.

I saw one in [Visual c++](http://bytescout.com/products/developer/swfscoutsdk/display_flash_in_visualc.html)

As per Chris's I checked the link. I tried adding these lines of code:

```
path = @"D:\exampleFlex\MainMenu.swf";
            axShockwaveFlash1.LoadMovie(0, path);
            axShockwaveFlash1.Play();
```

However, this swf was from Flash Builder and not Flash, hence there were other files like

```
framework_4.1.0.16076.swz  rpc_4.1.0.16076.swz    sparkskins_4.1.0.16076.swz
osmf_flex.4.0.0.13495.swz  spark_4.1.0.16076.swz  textLayout_1.1.0.604.swz
playerProductInstall.swf
```

http://help.adobe.com/en_US/flex/using/WS2db454920e96a9e51e63e3d11c0bf663fe-7fff.html

Hence, I could only see the background color of the swf, the swf did not play.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1037/displaying-flash-content-in-a-c-winforms-application

Comment: @Chris: thanks a lot; this swf was from Flash Builder and not Flash,

Comment: :) a swf is just a swf. Doesn't matter from where it comes. Try the solution from the link. It will work.

Comment: @Chris: Flex 4 enable creating swf which are optimized for speed, so by default they are dynamically linked to the SDK libs. Thats why I found so many swfs and swz in my bin-release. Also, the flex compiler produces html wrappers by default as these are RIAs. I guess I had to dig deep into Flex now; i had to use static linking. http://help.adobe.com/en_US/flex/using/WS2db454920e96a9e51e63e3d11c0bf69084-7add.html

Answer (score 1):

Could you just host WebBrowser component, which has html code to host flash?

Comment: I suppose it's a way to go, albeit much like getting a swiss army knife if all you need is a can opener.