# Is there a Flash API that allows access to controls and contents?

Tags: flash, api

I'm looking for an API that will allow an external program to access the internals of a Flash object, such as controls and their properties. Is there any way that a .net or Java app can interface with a flash object in this way?

Comment: Do you want to run the Flash object inside a browser, or a real program?

Comment: Inside a program - something other than a browser-based JavaScript engine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look at this thread:

[Displaying Flash content in a C# WinForms application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1037/displaying-flash-content-in-a-c-sharp-winforms-application)

In .NET you can use the Shockwave Flash Object. I believe you can access properties from there.